Authorization issues in Apps Script to access Gmail from Sheets
I am trying to show the latest email body for emails in a google sheet.  The sheet is for personal use and has been developed in my own google account accessing my own gmail account.  The code fails on this function:
function getMostRecentEmailInfo(emailAddress) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:' + emailAddress, 0, 1); // Search for emails from the specific email address
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
    var mostRecentMessage = messages[messages.length - 1]; // Get the most recent email
    var emailText = mostRecentMessage.getPlainBody(); // Extract the text of the email
    var emailDate = mostRecentMessage.getDate(); // Extract the date of the email

    return "On: " + emailDate + ". Wrote: " + emailText
  } else {
    return 'No email found from ' + emailAddress;
  }
}

With this execution error:

I think I have the relevant authorisations in place.  The appsscript.json is:
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "MYSELF"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
  ]
}

Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error and how to fix it?
For reference, here is the complete code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  // Check if the edited cell is the one with the dropdown box
  if (range.getA1Notation() == "B1" && sheet.getName() == "Workbench") {
    var selectedValue = e.value; // Get the value that was selected in the dropdown box
    if (selectedValue === "Pending") {
      selectedValue = ""
    }
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workbench");
    
    if(outputSheet.getLastRow() >= 4) {//clear down the previous rows
      outputSheet.getRange(4, 1, outputSheet.getLastRow() - 3, outputSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    }
    
    var outputData = [];
  
    //Website form response data
    var sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1"); 
    var data = sheetToCopy.getDataRange().getValues();
    //Name, Email, Date, Response, Additional,Source
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      //status, date, email, name, question, interested in
      if (row[0] === selectedValue) { // Check if the 1st column value is "Active"
        var outputRow = []
        outputRow[0] = row[3]
        outputRow[1] = createGmailHyperlink(row[2])
        outputRow[2] = row[1]
        outputRow[3] = row[4]
        outputRow[4] = row[5]
        outputRow[5] = "Website Form"
        outputRow[6] = getMostRecentEmailInfo(row[2])

        outputData.push(outputRow);
      }
    });

    //BSAC Find It tool responses
    sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName("BSAC Responses"); 
    data = sheetToCopy.getDataRange().getValues();
    //Name, Email, Date, Response, Additional,Source
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      //status, date, name, email, telephone, interested in, additional details
      if (row[0] === selectedValue) { // Check if the 1st column value is "Active"
        var outputRow = []
        outputRow[0] = row[2]
        outputRow[1] = createGmailHyperlink(row[3])
        outputRow[2] = row[1]
        outputRow[3] = row[6]
        outputRow[4] = row[5]
        outputRow[5] = "BSAC Find It"
        //outputRow[6] = getMostRecentEmailInfo(row[3])

        outputData.push(outputRow);
      }
    });

    //Direct
    sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName("Direct"); 
    data = sheetToCopy.getDataRange().getValues();
    //Name, Email, Date, Response, Additional,Source
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      //status, date, name, email, telephone, interested in
      if (row[0] === selectedValue) { // Check if the 1st column value is "Active"
        var outputRow = []
        outputRow[0] = row[2]
        outputRow[1] = createGmailHyperlink(row[3])
        outputRow[2] = row[1]
        outputRow[3] = row[5]
        outputRow[4] = ""
        outputRow[5] = "Direct"
        //outputRow[6] = getMostRecentEmailInfo(row[3])

        outputData.push(outputRow);
      }
    });
    
    if (outputData.length > 0) {
      outputSheet.getRange(outputSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
    }
  }
}

function createGmailHyperlink(emailAddress) {
  var gmailLink = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/to%3A' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '+OR+from%3A' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress);
  var hyperlinkFormula = '=HYPERLINK("' + gmailLink + '", "' + emailAddress + '")';

  return hyperlinkFormula;
}

function getMostRecentEmailInfo(emailAddress) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:' + emailAddress, 0, 1); // Search for emails from the specific email address
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
    var mostRecentMessage = messages[messages.length - 1]; // Get the most recent email
    var emailText = mostRecentMessage.getPlainBody(); // Extract the text of the email
    var emailDate = mostRecentMessage.getDate(); // Extract the date of the email

    return "On: " + emailDate + ". Wrote: " + emailText
  } else {
    return 'No email found from ' + emailAddress;
  }
}


I found this very helpful.  I had not defined my trigger as an installable trigger, so, although it was firing when I wanted it to (on edit of a spreadsheet cell), it did not have the required authorization.  As soon as I linked the onEdit(e) to an Installable Trigger (the clock icon) the sheet required authorisation and is now working as intended.

You should change the name of the trigger handler function, otherwise onEdit will be fired twice.

Yes, it was doing that.  Thanks.
